# Jquery custom css on odd / even clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rotate an object with .css
First click: 180°
Second click: back to normal position (+180°)

Now i need a function, to detect, if the current click is even or odd ...

Tried it with this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".board-element").find(".category div").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".board-boards").slideToggle(1000);
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        if (clicks) {
            $(this).css("transform", "none");
        } else {
            //first click
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
        }
        
    });

});
```

It works fine, i klick on the element, the object rotates ...
But when i click again, nothing happens ...

I hope you can understand my problem,
Thanks :)

Comment: You do not seem to be setting a `data('clicks')` value anywhere...

Answer (score 3):

Cleaner approach would be toggling class name so you don't have to deal with click counts:

```
$(".board-element").find(".category div").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".board-boards").slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass('rotate');    
});
```

CSS:

```css
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Additional benefit is that if you decide to support vendor prefixes you don't have to change javascript code for this, just extend CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to be setting a `data('clicks')` value anywhere...

```
$(function() {
    $(".board-element").find(".category div").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".board-boards").slideToggle(1000);
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        // Save the new flag value
        $(this).data('click', true);
        if (clicks) {
            $(this).css("transform", "none");
        } else {
            //first click
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
        }

    });

});
```

**Notes:**

- You should avoid things like `.parent().parent()` and use `closest('.board-element')` or similar instead.

@dfsq has posted a cleaner solution. This one was just to explain where you went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger variable, that changes its value after animation 2 directions (you have to inizialize it ouside the function):

```
var already_turned = false;

$(function() {
    $(".board-element").find(".category div").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".board-boards").slideToggle(1000);
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

        if (clicks && already_turned) {
            $(this).css("transform", "none");
            already_turned = false;
        } else {
            //first click
            $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
            already_turned = true;
        }

    });

});
```